# Options for running 64-bit guest (OpenShift Origin) in VirtualBox if hardware acceleration is not available?

Tags: virtualbox, hardware-acceleration, openshift-origin

**Environment:**

Motherboard: Asus P5Q3 Deluxe

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz 2.34 GHz

Installed Memory (RAM): 4.00GB

OS:  Windows 7 Home Premium

**Scenario:**

I am trying to run [OpenShift Origin](https://www.openshift.com/products/origin) in VirtualBox and when clicking 'Start' I am getting the error:

"VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot".

From my searches on the internet, it seems that such a setting is [available in the BIOS](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/19899-hardware-acceleration-good-bad-2.html#post213674) however I have been unable to find it.

So I am considering that such an option may not be available on my system?

If this is the case, what options do I have in regards to running OpenShift Origin in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification on the Intel website suggests that your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization (look for the 'Virtualization Technology (VT-x)' setting):

http://ark.intel.com/products/36547/intel-core2-quad-processor-q8200-4m-cache-2_33-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb

Hardware virtualization is a requirement for 64-bit guests in VirtualBox, and there is no workaround.